# How to select the value of dropdown list in a form using ruby/mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

How do I select the second option in this dropdown?

```
<select name="size" onchange="...js...">
  <option value="OPTION_CHOOSE">Please Select an Option</option>                            
  <option value="123">ABC</option>
  <option value="456">DFG</option>
  <option value="789">HIJ</option>
</select>
```

## ruby

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

url = "http://...."
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(url)

form = agent.page.forms.first

*select drop down*
```

Comment: Check this blog post : [Selecting an option from dropdown form fields with Mechanize](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/11/20/selecting-an-option-from-dropdown-form-fields-with-mechanize/) Seems to be addressing the same issue.

Comment: That blog post seemed very messy and confusing, I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
form.field_with(:name => 'size').options[1].click
```

Comment: thanks - not using mechanize anymore because the values are loaded post page load with AJAX and mechanize returns empty fields. Using a web driver. TY anyways

Comment: You probably gave up too soon. In general, those ajax calls are much easier to deal with with mechanize than watir. Faster and more reliable too.

Comment: I'd like to rewaken this query folks! have any of you figured out how to deal with this ajax stuff with mechanize? I'm looking for a mechanize solution because webdriver is too slow for me...

Comment: actually webdriver is reasonably fast... but its too memory intensive for significant parallel processing..

Comment: An ajax request is the same as any other request. Just use Mechanize#get

Comment: what if we like to select, based on provided external value by checking each  value.